# Is it possible to study de Rham Cohomology of surfaces through Riemann surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, riemann-surfaces, de-rham-cohomology

I am studying de Rham Cohomology of surfaces.  I am following the book "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Loring Tu. I found that it uses the "Mayer Veitoris Sequence" and notions of Homology. But I want to study it more geometrically.  My question is as follows. For an orientable two dimensional manifold (i.e.  orientable surface), we can view it as a Riemann surface. Can we study de Rham Cohomology  through Riemann surfaces?  Please advise.

If yes, please advise me about some references and the learning road map.

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "throw it in?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan Actually I meant that "Can we study de Rham Cohomology through Riemann surfaces?" I have edited now.

Comment: What is your goal? Would you like to compute de Rham cohomology of surfaces? Then the book you're currently following is a pretty good reference.

Comment: You may already know that de Rham cohomology is topological invariant, meaning that the complex structure endowed on the manifold has no effect on its de Rham cohomology. So any text that treats the surfaces as Riemann will not have a very different way of computing the de Rham cohomology.

Comment: But there are certain invariants which arise due to the complex structure on the Riemann surfaces, namely, Doulbeault cohomology. If your goal is to learn about those and their relation with de Rham cohomology, then Donaldson's and Forster's book are standard references.

Comment: However, I must say that I disagree with your criticism of Tu's book. I don't see how Mayer-Vietoris sequence is not _'geometric'_ enough. Also, as far as I am aware, Tu doesn't talk about homology. He just talks about de Rham cohomology.

Comment: I highly recommend the book *Algebraic Topology: A First Course* by William Fulton.

Comment: @feynhat I have understood your advise. But my question is: Can we compute de Rham cohomology of surfaces using Riemann surfaces? If  yes, please advise about the roadmap.

Comment: Again, the complex structure of the Riemann structure has not effect on the de Rham cohomology. So, the most straight forward way to compute de Rham cohomology of Riemann surfaces is no different from smooth surfaces.